Python 3.10.4 scikit-learn import hangs when executing via CPP
Python 3.10.4 is embedded into cpp application.
I'm trying to import sklearn library which is installed at custom location using pip --target.
sklearn custom path (--target path) is appended to sys.path.
Below is a function from the script which just prints the version information.
Execution using Command Line works well as shown below.
python3.10 -c 'from try_sklearn import *; createandload()'

Output
[INFO ] [try_sklearn.py:23] 3.10.4 (main, Aug  4 2023, 01:24:50) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)]
[INFO ] [try_sklearn.py:24] sklearn /users/xxxx/temp/python/scikit-learn/sklearn/__init__.py Version = 1.5.1

The same script when called using CPP, hangs at
import sklearn

Other libraries like pandas, numpy etc works without any issues.

Have you used a debugger to figure out what happens when it hangs?

Thanks for looking into this. It hangs at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L123

Right, and you're sure that Scipy is the correct version for your embedded Python?

I installed using pip using the same python3.10 binary.

Scipy 21189
Looks like Scipy and Numpy do not support Embedded python

I think the issue with embedded Python is if you stop and restart the interpreter. If you only start the interpreter once then it should be fine. Your question doesn't say either way

I'm not sure about this and the cpp code is a full stack application and I execute python script when only necessary. This might mean that I might be starting the interpreter multiple times.

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/21189
Looks like Scipy and Numpy do not support Embedded python

Yes, they do support embedded Python in C++. In your C++ code you need to include #include <Python.h>. Have you done that? Also, try to import only packages that you need in your Python code. For instance use "from sklearn import linear_model".

of course I have included python.h.
Both "import sklearn" and from sklearn import linear_model has same behavior.
